# Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to insert multiple rows in sql here is my code

```
if(!empty(trim($array[0])) && !empty(trim($array[1])))
        $sql[]  =   "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
}
```

but i am getting this error

> Can't use function return value in write context in /update/insert-content.php on line 41

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP 5.5, [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) only supports variables. Like the documentation says, use `trim($array[0]) == false` to check if a string is empty. In this case:

```
if(trim($array[0]) && trim($array[1]))
```

An empty string, and the string "0" are values that are considered `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok but I would use the empty function.

```
$array = ['hello', 'world'];
    if(trim($array[0]) && trim($array[1]))
    {
    $sql[]  =   "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
    }

    print_r($sql);
```

if the variable is null, or empty or an empty string
then this logic will not pass

```
  $variable
  if($variable){
    //if variable is empty then this will not run
}
```